# Compare with csv values with database rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a list of csv values, as in ('one','two', 'three','four'), and these values also exist in database in a column.

Now I want to know all the value's in the csv list, which DO NOT exist in database.

For example if my database column has values 'one', 'three', 'five', 'six', 'seven'.

Then my result should return values 'two' and 'four', as these exist in my list but do not exist in database.

sounds like its something simple, but I am stuck.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04e1b5/2) is the sql fiddle link with example.

Code for someone who does not want to use sqlfiddle (for whatever reason):

```
create table testcsv(
  csvnumber varchar2(100)
  );

INSERT ALL
  INTO testcsv VALUES ('one')
  INTO testcsv VALUES ('three')
  INTO testcsv VALUES ('five')
  INTO testcsv VALUES ('six')
  INTO testcsv VALUES ('seven')
SELECT * FROM dual;

select csvnumber from testcsv where csvnumber IN('one', 'two','three', 'four');
```

P.S: actual scenario is obviously much complex, I have simplified it to get the idea.

Comment: Where does the list come from?  You'd probably need to get that list into a relational structure.  That's trivial if your list is coming from a `SELECT` statement against some other table.  If it's coming from somewhere else, that's a bit more painful.

Comment: It isn't coming from another table, then I could just join them, its a static list of values supplied by someone else.

Comment: Can I do what I need without creating a new table and storing data, by maybe using the dual table?

Comment: Supplied how.  Are they passing a comma-separated string to a stored procedure, for example, that is running the query?  If so, you can parse the string into a local collection and use that.

Comment: No, it isn't part of whole such process, lets assume these values come in a daily mail and I have to extract these values manually.

Comment: Can you transform it into a `select from dual`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91134/discussion-between-user1933888-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around.

the solution is available on sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04e1b5/4)

Query:

```
(select substr(csv, 
   instr(csv,',',1,lev) + 1, 
   instr(csv,',',1,lev+1 )-instr(csv,',',1,lev)-1) 
from 
  (select ','||'one,two,three,four'||',' csv from dual), 
  (select level lev from dual connect by level <= 100) 
where lev <= length(csv)-length(replace(csv,','))-1)
MINUS
select csvnumber from testcsv where csvnumber IN('one', 'two','three', 'four');
```

Maybe not the best solution, but works for me, right now.